# Android HttpClient.execute not working

Tags: android, http-post, httpclient

I have an AsyncTask as follow:

```
@Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
    ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.URL);
        // Add your data
        List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(
                2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",params[0]));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

        // deal with response here
        ....


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Debug", e + " " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, on Jellybean, after running the app for a certain time, the code only runs to httpclient.execute(httppost) and stops right there.

Can anyone help me on that?

Comment: Some message displayed on your LogCat?

Comment: Where are you calling this AsyncTask and are you calling a postExecute method?  Nothing happens to the UI in doInBackground()

Answer (score 0):

Try this things:

1.Check your network connection and your server availability.

2.Check you have added the internet permission to your manifest.

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application ...
</manifest>
```

If I didn't misunderstand "after certain time", your are saying that it never successes and it always stops there. This could be because of permissions or your net connection because the request seems not to return.

If it runs sometimes yes but not others, I think it must be due to your server side.

I recommend you using https://github.com/matessoftwaresolutions/AndroidHttpRestService

I promise I will push a new commit with Android Studio folder structure.